# Launch ASP.Net project after build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, build-process

When working with an ASP.Net application, when I rebuild the solution, I would like it to automatically refresh the current version thats running through the integrated server in the browser.

I have looked through post build commands and afterbuild targeting but I have not been successful so far. I would like to do this straight through VS2008 if possible without needing to install anything extra, put if thats not possible then any solution would do!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with AutoIt

Create a script with the following code in it

```
WinActivate("Enter the name of your web app here")
Send("^{F5}")
```

Next put the script into a batch file and call the batch file in the postBuild event.
This will refresh the page after successful build.